# How to use OutputStream within try-with-resources properly?

Tags: java, outputstream

I have a simple piece of code, that works not the way I expect it to:

```
        try (OutputStream ostr = new BufferedOutputStream(System.out)) {
            ostr.write("lol".getBytes());
        }
        System.out.println("hmmm");
```

It results in just

```
lol
```

printed, but not `hmm`.

What am I doing wrong? Am I correct assuming that `hmm` isn't being printed because `ostr` closes `System.out` as well? I understand that this is a pretty synthetic example, but I'm still expecting for an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The try construct closes `ostr` at the end. Closing is propagated to `System.out`. A subsequent call to `System.out.println("hmmm");` will bring `System.out` into trouble - but not throw an exception. (That is the strange way `PrintStream`s handle errors.) Try this:

```
System.out.close();
System.out.println("hmmm");
System.err.println("System.out in trouble: " + System.out.checkError());
```

This prints (through the still intact System.err stream):

```
System.out in trouble: true
```

Comment: Uhm... I see, that's really weird. Actually, the reason why I'm asking is somewhat unexpected behavior of Jackson's `mapper.writeValue(OutputStream, Object)` method. After a single write the instance of `OutputStream` seems to be closed and unavailable for further writes: http://pastebin.com/hrcemPjv successfully prints during the first invocation of `write` an sets the error as a result of the next call. Seems like a bad design for me.

Comment: At least it seems a unexepected default behavior. I just clicked around in Jackson Javadoc a bit and read that you need a JsonFactory to create an ObjectMapper. The JsonFactory allows for something like `jsonFactor.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_TARGET, false)`. That might cure the unexpected behavior, but I did not try it.

Comment: Yeah, that seems like an option to me, too, but, IMO, this behavior IS an odd one to choose as default. And yes, that works. Thanks again.